# How would I add a new row above A2 when A2 is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm setting up a sheet for inventory info within **Google Sheets**; I'd like to add a new row above the edited one when someone signs out inventory automatically.

for example, when someone goes to check out an item, it should show [the last row and last date entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZr2A.png)

After someone enters their info, it should insert [a new row with the existing formatting and alternating colors settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WjJp.png)

I have already tried doing this manually by right-clicking on A2 and inserting above, maybe I did something wrong, but it inserted the new row with default colors and formatting. It may just be cosmetic, but it means something to me, at least.

Comment: Look up onEdit trigger or simple triggers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Your Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart == 2 && e.value) {
    sh.insertRowBefore(2);
  }
}
```